# Is there a SQL query to prevent two identical names in a column? And a query for the columns not to be left blank?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have created mutiple tables inside a database using PhpMyAdmin. But I cant find out how to do this:

It should not be allowed with two identical names in one of my columns. The column is called "name".
And I have one column called "prod_time" and one called "stock_ant" that must be filled in. (Like it's not going to be an option to leave it blank or with zero value)

Is there multiple queries to use for these actions?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying there are only two rows?

Comment: It's 3 columns and I need some particular values from one of them. About 20 rows

Answer (score 1):

If you want a column to have unique values, use a unique constraint or index.  For instance:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_name unique (name);
```

If you don't want columns to have `NULL` values, then declare them `NOT NULL` when you create the table.

Comment: Or set the [name] column as the primary key, which also sets a unique constraint.